# Deploying YugabyteDB on Azure by following the AWS tutorial

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I’m following this https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/public-clouds/aws/manual-deployment/ AWS tutorial for deploying on Azure.
In the replica placement policy — do you have the syntax for azure parameters for the region and zones. The parameters different AWS and Azure, the sample code AWS parameters on the site.

Answer (score 0):

The `placement_cloud`, `placement_region` and `placement_zone` are simply logical names to make it possible to understand placement, and can be named anything you like, for which it makes sense to describe the current cloud configuration.